# NoClassDefFoundException for a custom class(extends interface) after using Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, noclassdeffounderror

I am facing an issue while trying to apply ProGuard on a private library release - written in Kotlin. Without ProGuard, the AAR file generated works perfectly out of the box but after applying ProGuard, I have the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/package/name/CustomInterface$DefaultImpls;
```

The `CustomClass` that I need implements the CustomInterface but when I try to call any method of the `CustomClass`, I get this error.

Already tried setting the kotlinOptions.JvmTarget=1.8 but doesn't work.

Comment: You need to exclude from obfuscation/minification anything which is "public" and should be used by library consumer.
Probably you need to add a `keep` rule for you class and interface

Comment: I already did, I see the CustomClass & CustomInterface both in the compiled aar.

Comment: Have you tried enabling multiDex in your app? Add `multiDexEnabled true` if you have minSDK >= 21, otherwise follow the guide here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle